# ExcelDataReader in C# - How to reference an individual Cell using row and column cordinates

Tags: c#, excel, azure

I'm reading an .xlsx spreadsheet into a C# console app with a view to outputting the content as a formatted xml file (to be picked up by another part of the system further down the line).

The problem with the the .xslx file is that it's a pro-forma input document based on, and replacing, an old paper-based order form we used to provide to customers, and the input fields aren't organised as a series of similar rows (except in the lower part of the document which consists of up to 99 rows of order detail lines). Some of the rows in the header part of the form/sheet are a mixture of label text AND data; same with the columns.

Effectively, what I need to do is to be able to cherry pick data from the initial dozen or so rows in order to poke data into the xml structure; the latter part of the document I can process by iterating over the rows for the order detail lines.

I can't use Interop as this will end up as an Azure function - so I've used ExcelDataReader to convert the spreadsheet to a dataset, then convert that dataset to a new dataset entirely composed of string values. But I haven't been able to successfully point to individual cells as I had expected to be using syntax something like

```
var cellValue = MyDataSet.Cell[10, 2];
```

I'd be grateful for any advice as to how I might get the result I need.

Comment: But I assume that dataset has `var cellValue = MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[10][2];` ?

Comment: Yes it does!! That's exactly what I was looking for :D ! Thanks rene, If you post your comment as a Solution I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-5.0) has [Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.item?view=net-5.0) and those have [Rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection?view=net-5.0) which hold [ColumnValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-5.0)

A WorkSheet transforms into a Table (with Columns) and the Cells transform to Rows and column values.

To find the cell value at [10,2] on the first Worksheet do:

```
var cellValue = MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[10][2];
```

Remember that cellValue will be of type `object`. Cast accordingly.